# How to decrease the space between column

Tags: java, android

I have this table:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TableLayout

        android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_width="369dp"
        android:layout_height="118dp"


        android:layout_marginTop="224dp"


        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:text="A:" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="15%" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/editTextBackground"

                android:layout_weight="1.5"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:textColor="#000000"  />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:text="20%" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/editTextBackground"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:text="25%" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/editTextBackground"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/a1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:text="B:" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/a2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="15%" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/b1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/editTextBackground"
                android:textColor="#000000"
            />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/b2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:text="20%" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/b3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/editTextBackground"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/b4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:text="25%" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/b5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/editTextBackground"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

How to make the columns closer together?

To make less space between 15% and underscore?

Comment: try with paddingRight or marginRight -20dp or -10dp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used below codes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TableLayout

        android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_width="369dp"
        android:layout_height="118dp"


        android:layout_marginTop="224dp"


        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"

                android:text="A:" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="15%" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:background="?attr/editTextBackground"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="20%" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/editTextBackground"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="25%" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/editTextBackground"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/a1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"

                android:text="B:" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/a2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="15%" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/b1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/editTextBackground"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/b2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="20%" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/b3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/editTextBackground"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/b4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="25%" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/b5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/editTextBackground"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


Output :
```

[image: Screen Shot]